# Weird session ehavior with a model which is associated to User

Tags: cakephp

I have a problem with sessions. The user can have a company or a town. For the town, I can do with Auth.Town posted the information about the city (town_id of the table users = id of the table towns). It's the same thing for companies (company_id = id), the problem is that I can not create sessions: Auth.Company, there is a connection problem, as you can see in my array I have an id value that is 3 and name is test, this corresponds to the id of the company 3 table when I should have the information of the id 16. What is it going on? An error in my models?

```
 [Auth] => Array
        (
            [User] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 96
                    [email] => jetest@test.com
                    [avatar] => 
                    [firstname] => Brian
                    [lastname] => Ferui
                    [created] => 2014-09-22 11:05:55
                    [modified] => 2014-09-22 11:05:55
                    [role] => user
                    [town_id] => 0
                    [company_id] => 16
                )

            [Company] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [name] => test
                    [legal_form] => 
                )

        )
```

Model User :

```
<?php 

class User extends AppModel{


  public $actsAs = array(
    'Upload' => array(
        'fields' => array(
            'avatar' => 'img/avatars/:id1000/:id'
      )
    )
  );

    public $hasOne = array(
        'Company' => array(
            'className' => 'Company',
            'foreignKey' => 'id',
            'dependent' => true
        ),
        'Town' => array(
            'className' => 'Town',
            'foreignKey' => 'id',
            'dependent' => true
        )
    );

    public $recursive = -1; 

    public $order = 'User.id DESC';

    public $validate = array(

        'email' => array(

            'rule'       => 'isUnique',

            'allowEmpty' => false,

            'message'    => "Ce adresse e-mail est déja prise ou vide..."

        ),
         'password' => array(
          array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty',
            'allowEmpty' => false,
            'message' => 'Le mot de passe ne peux pas être vide...'
          ),
          array(
            'rule' => array('minLength', 4),
            'message' => 'Le mot de passe doit avoir au moins 4 caractères...'
          )
      ),
        'firstname' => array(
          array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty',
            'message' => 'Le prénom ne peux pas être vide...'
          )
      ),
        'lastname' => array(
          array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty',
            'message' => 'Le nom ne peux pas être vide...'
          )
      ),
    'avatar_file' => array(
          array(
            'rule' => array('fileExtension', array('jpg','png')),
            'message' => 'Extension invalide...'
          )
      )
    );

    public function beforeSave($options = array()){

        if(!empty($this->data['User']['password'])){

            $this->data['User']['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data['User']['password']);

        }

        return true; 

    }

}
```

Model Company :

```
<?php 

class Company extends AppModel{

  public $actsAs = array(
    'Upload' => array(
        'fields' => array(
            'logo' => 'img/logos/:id1000/:id'
      )
    )
  );

 public $hasMany = array(
    'User' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'company_id',
        'dependent' => false
    ));

    public $validate = array(
    'name' => array(
          array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty',
            'message' => 'Le nom de l\'entreprise ne peux pas être vide...'
          )
      ),
    'logo_file' => array(
          array(
            'rule' => array('fileExtension', array('jpg','png')),
            'message' => 'Extension invalide...'
          )
      )
    );

}



?>
```

function login in UsersController

```
    public function login() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if (isset($this->request->data['UserLogin'])) {
            $this->request->data['User'] = $this->request->data['UserLogin'];
     } 

        if ($this->Auth->login()) {

    if ($this->Auth->user('town_id') > '0') {

    $towns = array('name', 'country', 'localisation', 'statut');
foreach($towns as $column) {
    $this->Session->write(
        'Auth.Town.' . $column,
        $this->User->Town->field($column)
    );
}

}

    if ($this->Auth->user('company_id') > '0') {

    $companies = array('name', 'legal_form');
foreach($companies as $column) {
    $this->Session->write(
        'Auth.Company.' . $column,
        $this->User->Company->field($column)
    );
}

}

                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect()); 

            }else{

                $this->Session->setFlash("L'adresse électronique ou votre mot de passe ne correspond pas","notif",array('type'=>'error'));

            }
    }
}
```

What's weird is that it works for "Town" but not for "Company."
For Company, "Associated save" works in my signup function, so the connection is functional, I can not recovered values ​​for the sessions, why, I do not know, thank you ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by changing the [relationships](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#relationship-types) within the User model from hasOne to belongsTo.

- **hasOne** is for 1:1 relationships
- **belongsTo** is for M:1

Code changes should be:

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Company' => array(
        'className' => 'Company',
        'foreignKey' => 'company_id'
    ),
    'Town' => array(
        'className' => 'Town',
        'foreignKey' => 'town_id'
    )
);
```

Comment: Thanks ;) It's still the same, i guess it's the first id of the column which is used in my array for Auth.Company, it has to be the same value of company_id, so 16 ... it's weird :/ Do i need to change my company model too ?

Comment: @user3790914 - I believe your login code assumes the company and town are set prior to your use of the `field` method.  Try `$this->User->Company->id = $this->Auth->user('company_id')` as the first statement in the IF block.

Comment: Thanks, could you edit your post please ? Where will i have to put this code ? I mean in which condition ?

Comment: OMG it works ! i wrote this coe in the second statement . Thanks a lot !